# Keras LSTM input/output shape

Tags: python-3.x, lstm, keras-layer, keyerror

I need outputs at every recurrent layer and my setup is as follows:

100 training examples, 3 time steps per example, and 20-d feature vector for each individual element.

x_train: (100,3,20)

y_train: (100,20)

LSTM architecture:

```
model.add(LSTM(20, input_shape=(3,20), return_sequences=True))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Training:

```
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 20 and 3 for '{{node Equal}} = Equal[T=DT_FLOAT, incompatible_shape_error=true](IteratorGetNext:1, Cast_1)' with input shapes: [?,20], [?,3].
```

Please help me with the correct input/output LSTM dimensions.
Thanks

Comment: set return_sequences=False (your output is 2D) and pay attention to use accuracy, it's not a metric for regression problems

Comment: @YOGEZSH KALAKOTI, Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LSTM(20, input_shape=(3,20), return_sequences=True)` takes as input shape `(100,3,20)` and returns `(100,3,20)`. Your target output is however encoded as `(100,20)`.

From the dimensions, I assume you want to map each sequence to a non-sequence, i.e. you can do:

```
LSTM(20, input_shape=(3,20), return_sequences=False)
```

This will return the final hidden state, i.e. a shape of `(100,20)` which matches your target output.

Comment: Hey @runDOSrun, it should be a seq2seq model and (100, 3, 20)

Comment: Hey runDOSrun, 'LSTM(20, input_shape=(3,20), return_sequences=False)' works fine. But I need to build a seq2seq model, wherein for an input shape of '(100,3,20)', I can extract 'y' for every time step. What changes would you suggest in my code? 

My data is like (Assume all the words have have 20-d embeedings)
'(x,y): (cat dog mouse, zebra)'
'''(x,y): (dog mouse zebra hen)'''

Naturally, my x_train and y_train would be '(3x20)' and '(20)' respectively.